# Access object from lambda passed in object's constructor

Tags: java, lambda, constructor, new-operator

I have a Java class MyClass with this constructor:

```
public MyClass(Consumer<?> someMethod)
```

And I would like to do that:

```
final MyClass myObject = new MyClass(obj -> { 
    doSomethingOutsideTheContextOfMyObject();
    myObject.doSmomething(obj);
    });
```

But I get an compiler error that variable myObject might not be initialized.

According to my research I cannot switch of the compiler showing the error and I cannot fake-initialize the variable as it has to be final. What shall I do?

Comment: Would you consider to extend the ```MyClass``` adding the member method that implement such a lambda? Is this lambda something that would change from constructor call to call or  actually is fixed? Otherwise the BiConsumer solution below is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the lambda you are passing to your Constructor should not be a Consumer ; it should be a BiConsumer...

Something like that :

```
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class MyClass<T> {

    private BiConsumer<MyClass<T>, T> lambda;

    public MyClass(BiConsumer<MyClass<T>, T> lambda) {
        this.lambda = lambda;
    }

    private static void doSomethingOutside() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void doSomething(T obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void go(T o) {
        lambda.accept(this, o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass<String> myObj = new MyClass<>((me, obj) -> {
            doSomethingOutside();
            me.doSomething(obj);
        });

        myObj.go("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

HTH! :)

Comment: I did it that way. And it's not even as awkward as it initially appears.

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
final MyClass myObject
```

**declares** a new object `myObject`. And then you go on:

```
  = new MyClass(obj -> { 
  doSomethingOutsideTheContextOfMyObject();
  myObject.doSmomething(obj);
```

**using** the very same `myObject` within its own declaration!

That isn't possible like that! You are creating a "self-reference" in circular ways!